# Kendo grid sortable column doesn't sort

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik-grid

I was create kendo grid with `sortable: true` property and turn off sorting for some columns by setting property `sortable` to `false`

```
    this._grid = $('#findResultsGrid').kendoGrid ({
                        sortable: true,
                    groupable: {
                        messages: {
                            empty: 'drag columns here'
                        }
                    },
                    scrollable: true,
                        columns:[
                            {
                                width: '100px',
                                title: 'Project',
                                field: 'PROJECT',
                                template: '<p style="' + defaultStyle + '">#=PROJECT#</p>'
                            },
                            {
                                width: '100px',
                                title: 'Well',
                                field: 'SLHOLENAME',
                                sortable: false,
                                template: '<p style="' + defaultStyle + '">#=SLHOLENAME#</p>'
                            },

...
```

But some columns without sort disabling (has no option `sortable: false`) not sortings and looks as not sortable

Comment: can you tell something more? what columns? every time the same? can you reproduce it in some fiddle? in kendo example it works perfectly: http://dojo.telerik.com/IBowu

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i found my own bug while prepared reproducing example - unsortable columns has not filled field property

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. The `field` property of a column needs to be set for column sorting to work. Since:

> [columns.sortable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.sortable): If set to `true` the user can click the column header and sort the grid **by the column field** when sorting is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Another case of this problem is when you have numerical fields if one of them is `0`, it will be considered as not set.

To fix this, prefix an empty string to it to force its conversion to string:

```
field: '' + item.field,
```